# Gnome applications not playing alert sounds in KDE Plasma

Tags: gnome, sound, kde

I have recently switched from Gnome to KDE Plasma on my Ubuntu 20.04. Everything works fine, the only problem is that the Gnome applications do not play any alert sound inside KDE Plasma, but KDE applications do.

Why does this happen? Is there any workaround to make Gnome applications play alert sounds in KDE Plasma?

Comment: Can you tell us which applications? Have you already checked under *System Settings > Personalization > Notifications?*  Specifically in the *"Event source:"* drop-down

Comment: I have noticed this issue with `Gnome terminal` and `Gnome system monitor`. I have searched in the *System settings Notifications* section, but there is no "*Event source*" dropdown.